# MySQL query looping through all the entries in ti

Tags: python, mysql

I have this code:

```
get_amounts_sum = []
query = """SELECT sp.customer_surname, SUM(sp.amount),
(Select SUM(cp.amount) from customers_payments7777 cp
where cp.customer_AFM = sp.customer_AFM AND sp.date_ <= %s AND cp.date_ <= %s
GROUP BY sp.customer_AFM) amountsum,
sp.monthly, sp.date_ 
FROM set_payment7777 sp
GROUP BY customer_AFM"""

mycursor.execute(query,(to_date,to_date,))
for row in mycursor:
    if row[3].upper() == 'Y':
        num_months = (to_date.year - row[4].year) * 12 + (to_date.month - row[4].month)
        semi_final_amount_Y = (row[1] * num_months) + row[1] 
        final_amount_Y = semi_final_amount_Y - row[2]
        file.write(f"{row[0]}\t{final_amount_Y}\t")
        file.write("\n")
    elif row[3].upper() == 'N':
        final_amount_N = row[1] - row[2]
        file.write(f"{row[0]}\t{final_amount_N}\t")
        file.write("\n")
```

It is getting two amounts from two different tables in MySQL. Also, the first table has a variable called monthly. Some amounts have that variable set to Y (yes) and some amounts set to N (no). I want to take all the amounts that have it set to Y, then multiply them by the length of months between two dates, and then subtract them from the amounts in the second table. If it's not set to Y, I want to do the same but without the multiplication by the months. The code above is working fine but the problem is that it checks if there is one amount that has the variable set to Y and then it is doing the process for all of the amounts. I don't want it I want to do it only for the amounts that have it set to Y and then proceed to the amounts that have it set to N.

Comment: Aside: There's no need for `GROUP BY sp.customer_AFM` in the subquery, since it's only selecting one `customer_AFM`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the issue correctly, you have two options, the easiest one, I believe, is order the result of the query so all  "Ys" are processed first:

```
"""SELECT sp.customer_surname, SUM(sp.amount),
(Select SUM(cp.amount) from customers_payments7777 cp
where cp.customer_AFM = sp.customer_AFM AND sp.date_ <= %s AND cp.date_ <= %s
GROUP BY sp.customer_AFM) amountsum,
sp.monthly, sp.date_ 
FROM set_payment7777 sp
GROUP BY customer_AFM
ORDER BY sp.monthly DESC"""
```

Alternatively you can have two queries and process them separately :

```
queryY = """SELECT sp.customer_surname, SUM(sp.amount),
(Select SUM(cp.amount) from customers_payments7777 cp
where cp.customer_AFM = sp.customer_AFM AND sp.date_ <= %s AND cp.date_ <= %s
GROUP BY sp.customer_AFM) amountsum,
sp.monthly, sp.date_ 
FROM set_payment7777 sp
WHERE sp.monthly='Y'
GROUP BY customer_AFM"""

queryN = """SELECT sp.customer_surname, SUM(sp.amount),
(Select SUM(cp.amount) from customers_payments7777 cp
where cp.customer_AFM = sp.customer_AFM AND sp.date_ <= %s AND cp.date_ <= %s
GROUP BY sp.customer_AFM) amountsum,
sp.monthly, sp.date_ 
FROM set_payment7777 sp
WHERE sp.monthly='N'
GROUP BY customer_AFM"""

mycursor.execute(queryY,(to_date,to_date,))
for row in mycursor:
        num_months = (to_date.year - row[4].year) * 12 + (to_date.month - row[4].month)
        semi_final_amount_Y = (row[1] * num_months) + row[1] 
        final_amount_Y = semi_final_amount_Y - row[2]
        file.write(f"{row[0]}\t{final_amount_Y}\t")
        file.write("\n")
        
mycursor.execute(queryN,(to_date,to_date,))
for row in mycursor:        
        final_amount_N = row[1] - row[2]
        file.write(f"{row[0]}\t{final_amount_N}\t")
        file.write("\n")
```